# Trying to use multi-thread to receive data of socket

Tags: python, select, tkinter

edit: After my plan changed (Bryan saying I could not use the 'select' library for TkInter)
I tried using multi-threading and I've typed something which doesn't seem to work:

```
def receive_data():
    try:
        (client_socket, address) = server_socket.accept()
        print client_socket.recv(1024)
    except socket.error:
        print 'error'


def server_window():
    window = Tk()
    data = ''
    activate_window(window, 666, 666)
    b1 = Button(window, text='RECEIVE DATA', fg='sienna', bg='khaki', command=lambda info=data: handle_waiter(info))
    b1.grid(sticky='W', row=2, column=0, columnspan=1)
    b1 = Button(window, text='ORDERS',  fg='sienna', bg='khaki', command=orders_window)
    b1.grid(sticky='W', row=1, column=0, columnspan=1)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_data())
    thread.start()

    window.mainloop()
```

Yet, what I have done seems to be blocking the GUI... I would be glad if anyone could help me

Comment: tkinter is single-threaded. If you have a function that blocks, you need to run that in another thread or process.

Comment: Hi Bryan could you guide me on what way to do that because I don't know how to use anything except for the select, which library would I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some time I managed to use select without it blocking my TKinter code,

for now i configured some random button(b5) to send a message (which should be blocking)

```
def rms_window(waiter):
    """MAIN WAITER'S WINDOW"""
    window = waiter.get_window()  # Main window called from the waiter class.
    activate_window(window, 600, 482)  # 600x482

    bg_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('bg_icon.png'))  # Image background picture.
    bg_label = Label(window, height=482, width=600, image=bg_icon)  # Create an image label for the window background.
    bg_label.place(x=0, y=0)

    order_list = Listbox(window, height=10, width=30, bg='white', fg='brown')  # Order list ListBox.
    sort_gui(window, order_list)  # sort scrollbar, labels and order list inside the waiter's window.

    menu_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('menu_icon.png'))  # Image of the menu button.
    b1 = Button(window, image=menu_icon)  # Append button to the main window and apply picture.
    set_gui(b1, 'Menu', 'cyan', 'cyan')
    b1.configure(command=lambda i=waiter.get_socket(): open_menu(waiter, order_list))  # on click - open menu window.
    b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    t1 = Text(window, width=25, height=1, bg='brown')  # Simple text box used to read bill number in the bill button
    t1.grid(row=14, column=0)

    b2 = Button(window)  # Bill button - reads text from variable t1 and sends the bill of the number given.
    set_gui(b2, 'Bill', 'pale goldenrod', 'chocolate')
    b2.configure(command=lambda i=waiter.get_socket(): send_bill('BILL ' + t1.get(1.0, END), i))
    b2.grid(row=15, column=0)  # Sends the bill to the server once you type an order number inside the textbox.

    b3 = Button(window)
    set_gui(b3, 'SEND ORDER', 'brown', 'chocolate')
    b3.configure(command=lambda i=waiter: i.send_order(order_list))  # On click send the whole order list to the server.
    b3.grid(row=10, column=0)  # Send the order listed in the list box widget.

    chat_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("chat_icon.png"))
    b4 = Button(window, image=chat_icon)  # Apply chat icon image to waiters chatting button.
    set_gui(b4, 'WAITERS CHAT', 'green', 'green')
    b4.configure(command=lambda i=waiter: waiters_chat(i))  # On click - opens the chat service.
    b4.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W')

    b5 = Button(window)
    set_gui(b5, 'TESTER', 'green', 'green')
    b5.configure(command=test_cmd(messages_to_send, waiter.get_socket()))
    b5.grid(row=5, column=5)

    read_list, write_list, x_list = select.select([waiter.get_socket()], [waiter.get_socket()], [])
    send_waiting_messages(write_list, messages_to_send)
    others_messages(read_list)
```

while the functions are:

```
def others_messages(read_list):
    for current_socket in read_list:
        try:
            data = current_socket.recv(1024)
            print data
        except:
            print "Connection with server closed."
            current_socket.close()


def send_waiting_messages(write_list, m_to_send):
    for message in m_to_send:
        (client_socket, data) = message
        if client_socket in write_list:
            print data
            client_socket.send(data)
            m_to_send.remove(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `target` of a thread is a callable.
What you're passing to `Thread`, on the other hand, is not `receive_data`, but `receive_data()`.

Long story short, the `receive_data` function is called on the current thread when you reach the point of the parameter evaluation for the `Thread` constructor, and you stay inside of it until it ends.

You just need to remove the parentheses, and create your thread as follows:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_data)
```

Comment: Thanks but now my thread is being called once, can't I keep receiving data forever? I don't want it to work only once